# Why does initialization of int by parenthesis inside class give error?

Tags: c++11

I was trying to initialize non-static member variable using parenthesis. I encountered this in Scott Meyers book (9th release) at page 50. The book says error but doesn't say why. May be I am not able to read between the lines. Is there reason why this fails. I just wanted to know the reason behind the fail.

```
#include <iostream>

struct B {};

struct C {
    C(int x) : val(x) {}

    int val;
};

class A {
   public:
    A(){};

   private:
    int x = 1; // fine
    int y{3}; // fine
    int z(0); // error
    B b;      // fine
    C c(4); // error
};

int main() {
    int x(5); // this works as well

    A a;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I think it is to avoid ambiguities. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: Not all forms of initialization can be used to perform in-class member initialization. That's what the standard says. Are you wondering why the standards committee made that decision?

Comment: @RSahu I think your first line answers my question. But me being curious .. Is Cris right about `vexing_parse`? Why did standards committee made that decision?

Comment: @solti, I don't know why the standards committee made that decision. Let's hope someone that does know the reason posts an answer.